# Not able to arrange data in descending order using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

[image]

I have created the above table on SQL workbench and trying to run a very basic query of giving the data in desc order according to salary (code shown below along with output) however I am not getting the correct output. Can anyone please help me with this

[image]

Comment: Is your `salary` column datatype is varchar?

Comment: cast your column salary to interger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`salary` is obviously a text field. Either change it to an numeric type (integer or decimal would be appropriate), or `CAST` it in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
ORDER BY CAST(salary AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the appropriate query for your solutions.

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY CAST(salary AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

NOTE- please try to maintain NORMALIZATION in your DATABASE. if the column is SALARY then try set datatype as MONEY. this will helps u a lot.